# Symfony 6 - Unable to make HtmlSanitizer work properly

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

Based on SF6 docs, I tried to use the new HtmlSanitizer component ( https://symfony.com/doc/current/html_sanitizer.html ) on some html that's coming from a database, nothing fancy, really:

```html
<section class="main">
    <div class="class-name">
        <p>
            This is a paragraph, with <strong>words</strong> in it, it also has a <a href="/some/relative/link">relative link</a> and a <a href="https://www.google.com/">absolute</a> one as well.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

When I pass this through the default sanitizer, the html output is:

```html
<section>
    <div>
        <p>
            This is a paragraph, with <strong>words</strong> in it, it also has a <a>relative link</a> and a <a href="https://www.google.com/">absolute</a> one as well.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

So my class attributes are removed, relative URLs as well, but oddly enough, absolute URLs are kept.

I tried to create a custom sanitizer, with the following configuration:

```yaml
framework:
    html_sanitizer:
        sanitizers:
            app.wysiwyg_sanitizer:
                allow_safe_elements: true
                allow_static_elements: true
                allow_relative_links: true
                allow_relative_medias: true
```

And when I use it, things almost work, except, the links containing absolute URLs, are rendered unusable:

```html
<section class="main">
    <div class="class-name">
        <p>
            This is a paragraph, with <strong>words</strong> in it, it also has a <a href="/some/relative/link">relative link</a> and a <a>absolute</a> one as well.
        </p>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's the PHP to it, not much going on:

```php
#[Route('/', name: 'app_home')]
    public function index(HtmlSanitizerInterface $sanitizer, HtmlSanitizerInterface $appWysiwygSanitizer): Response
    {
        $html = '
        <section class="main">
            <div class="class-name">
                <p>
                    This is a paragraph, with <strong>words</strong> in it, it also has a <a href="/some/relative/link">relative link</a> and a <a href="https://www.google.com/">absolute</a> one as well.
                </p>
            </div>
        </section>';

        $response = 'Default: ' . $sanitizer->sanitize($html);
        $response .= PHP_EOL;
        $response .= 'Custom: ' . $appWysiwygSanitizer->sanitize($html);

        return new Response($response);
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I just need those links to be rendered properly and I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: This has been sorted out, I was not properly clearing the app cache in order to see the new sanitizer changes applied properly. 

Additionally, as @Bl457Xor pointed out below, `allowed_link_schemes` must be specified as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to explicity allow the link schemes:

```
framework:
    html_sanitizer:
        sanitizers:
            app.wysiwyg_sanitizer:
                ...
                allowed_link_schemes: ['http', 'https', 'mailto']
```

**Edit:** it seems necessary to do a clear:cache after the config file modification, for it to take effect

Comment: I did try this before, without success. Afaik, they are allowed by default, including the `tel` scheme.

Comment: Actually, you might be on to something. When I tried the above option, I did the cleanup using twig and it just hit me that twig does cache on the output, so that might be the problem. Let me run some tests and get back to you.

Comment: Yes, the cache was the problem. I'll accept this answer as this lead me to find the fix. Thank you.

Comment: By testing I had also to clear cache after every config modification (even in dev env)